# how to change url pattern in struts action

Tags: jsp, url-rewriting, struts2

`domain/Forum_show.action?pg=2&forum=java`

How do I rewrite that to:

`domain/forum/java/pg/2`

Comment: You need to specify your requirements . . . in particular, do you really need to rewrite?  or do you just need to use rest-ish urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the URL structure you like right from the start. The ability to map to any URL structure is a feature of the Servlet API.

Also, you don't need to have an action extension (the .action part) in Struts2. In my opinion, creating bogus extensions never made sense.

Here are a few pages where I have talked about using Named Variable Pattern Matching in order to provide prettier URLs. I use this technique in all of my Struts2 apps and it yields much nicer URLs similar to your second example.

- [NamedVariablePatternMatcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772737/hidden-features-of-struts-2-framework/4837917#4837917)
- [Better URLs with Struts2](http://www.struts2.info/displaycontent/content/better-urls-with-struts2)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check [Struts REST Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/rest-plugin.html), which purpose is to follow Ruby on Rails URL style (just as you want).

Answer (score 2):

Both are good answers but you can use [UrlRewritefilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/). In this [link](http://www.progbear.com/voice/2010/struts-2-create-friendly-url-with-urlrewritefilter) there is an example of how to use in a Struts2 application.