# is it possible to make descriptive url from query url in struts2

Tags: java, struts2

is it possible to make descriptive url from query url in struts2

example: if the url is as below

query url : http://example.com/products?category=2&pid=25

descriptive url : http://example.com/products/2/25

Please suggest me.

Comment: May be this can help - http://www.progbear.com/voice/2010/struts-2-create-friendly-url-with-urlrewritefilter

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073951/how-to-change-url-pattern-in-struts-action/12076249#12076249

Comment: check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245373/struts2-pass-url-to-action/12248533#12248533